# Method whereYear does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5

so I have in my website a search for news by year or month so I used `whereYear` Method but for some reason its saying `methon whereYear` does not exist.

```
  $news = News::paginate(6);


    if ($year != null && $month != null){

        $news->whereYear('created_at','=',$year)->whereMonth('created_at','=',$month)->get();

    }
    if ($year != null && $month == null){
        $news->whereYear('created_at','=',$year)->get();

    }
    if ($year == null && $month != null){
        $news->whereMonth('created_at','=',$month)->get();
    }
```

and I have `laravel 5.5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use a method from the `Query Builder` on your instance of pagination.

Move your `paginate` call to the end and initiate your query with `::query()`.

```
$query = News::query(); 

if ($year != null && $month != null){
    $query->whereYear('created_at','=',$year)->whereMonth('created_at','=',$month);
}

if ($year != null && $month == null){
    $query->whereYear('created_at','=',$year);
}

if ($year == null && $month != null){
    $query->whereMonth('created_at','=',$month);
}

$news = $query->paginate(6);
```